# Android: Turn based network capable game engine

Tags: android, networking

This may be ambitious, but in stackoverflow i trust...

I am wondering about the capabilities and possible road blocks would be for creating a turn based network capable game engine for the android platform, and would be played in a similiar fashion to games such as "Words with Friends" ect.

This engine would be tailored to a card game and would only require data packets sent between peers every time a player takes his/her turn. Game resources such as images and sounds may have to be downloaded from a central server and stored on the android device's temporary storage in order to reduce the amount of storage that the app would have to permanently have on the device.

Before I invest a lot of time into this project I figured I would ask some initial questions.

1. What limitations/roadblocks does a seed/turn based network game provide to a developer?
2. Is integrating an ingame microtransaction based shop using a service such as PayPal a possibility?
3. Will packets between peers need to be encrypted to prevent cheating?
4. How is it possible to validate clients from a central server to prevent piracy?
5. What is the best method for balancing lightweight storage/cpu requirements, while still having crystal clear graphics?
6. Is it a good idea to learn java seperately from using the android SDK, or just jump right in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Networking adds complexity; see if you can make single player first
2. Yes, but frowned upon; Google prefers, and may some day insist, that you use their in-app feature.
3. Yes, if you substitute "discourage" for "prevent"
4. Login authentication for the networking to work is one way.
5. If the UI has 3D graphics, use OpenGL, otherwise, use Canvas or even HTML5
6. Jump

Comment: I'd +1 if I could. Additionally, since I am new to the android SDK and have experience with GML (gamemaker) I beleive I will construct a prototype with game maker, and create a mirrored project, porting each aspect as I go.